# Input events slow on unity Update function

Tags: unity, input, events

I have this running on the Update() on Unity.  I am trying to create a page swipe feature on my game, but the problem is there is a half second delay when printing "dragging" to "end drag" when I release the mouse.

Does anyone have a method that will register input events faster?

```
void Update()
{
    if(isDragOn)
    {           
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            print ("dragging");
            //moveContainers((Input.mousePosition.x - mouseLastPosition) * 0.01f);
            mouseLastPosition = Input.mousePosition.x;
        }
        else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            print ("end drag");
            isDragMoved = false;
            isDragOn = false;
            endDrag();
        }
        else if(Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                //moveContainers(Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x);
            }
            else if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
            {
                isDragMoved = false;
                isDragOn = false;
                endDrag();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your code on my machine, `end drag` is printed immediately when I release the mouse. I suggest you do some further debugging/optimization.

Comment: I delete everything except for the print functions and it is still slow.  Does that mean that my other code inside the script is affecting the update function?  I always thought that how fast or slow update function is is based on what's inside this function.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But it's also affected by every other script's `Update` function. Every script on every object has an `Update` function, they all get run every frame. You may have too many objects, or one of your scripts has an `Update` function that takes a very long time to complete.

Comment: cool. I'll check it out.

Comment: I disabled the entire script and created a new script.  I notice that when I tap, both button down and up register immediately.  However, when I drag, there is a lag and button up doesn't always register.

Comment: Strangely, when I start a new project and detect touch. it is also as slow. Time.deltaTime shows around 0.0164 for Tap and Drag. I am not sure that is accurate since Tap is much faster.

Comment: That's pretty strange. I'm not sure what to tell you, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't going to be something "faster" than `Update`([reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)), that runs once per frame:

> Update is called every frame, if the MonoBehaviour is enabled.

If your frame rate is half a second per frame, then you'll get a half second delay. You'll need to perform some optimizations if you want faster response. Make sure your MonoBehaviour is enabled, and you're not running `Update` as part of a [Coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html). You can try creating a new project, and just putting your code into a new script on an otherwise empty object.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse input can be theoretically speed up by using a callback-based input API. Because polling-based input API is going to be delayed from the actual input no matter what. Depending on the timing of the hardware, imagine at this moment the `Update` just passed but you are not yet at the rendering routine. If you were using callback-based input you would have 1 frame advantage and able to update the graphic in time. Unity have keep this callback data for the next frame.

Unity's [New Input System](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem) is callback-based. But currently (9/9/2018) as far as I tried the callback does not occur at an arbitrary time but [queued up and batched together](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-the-touch-screen-working-yet.544878/#post-3595679) and present the callback to you in the loop, before all `Update()`. There might be a way to ask the "queued up" data in the future when the API is being finalized, so I think it worths looking out for.

Because I see some touch code I am assuming you might also want the solution to work with touch input. If you use [Native Touch](http://exceed7.com/native-touch/) you can receive the native touch callbacks as soon as the touch happen, which could be faster than waiting for `Update`. If you want the same input workflow as native app developement you might want to check it out.

Comment: Asker isn't having problems with touch input, but mouse input.

Comment: That may not be true. You can see in his `Update()` code there are `Input.touchCount` and `Input.GetTouch(0)`, and also "Does anyone have a method that will register input events faster?", that is where I based my assumption from. And the foundation of this problem is because the check is based on in-frame input state polling in `Update()` instead of a callback.

Comment: From the question: *`there is a half second delay when printing "dragging" to "end drag" when I release the mouse.`* They stated "mouse" explicitly and "dragging" as a text string only appears under the mouse input section.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The asker is 100% having a problem with the mouse input. The touch problem is only a possibility, he might or might not having a problem with it.

Comment: I have edited the answer so that the mouse problem is addressed first, and then the touch problem which might or might not be a problem is addressed second.